# Is there a way to apply settings in MS Access without restarting the database?

Tags: ms-access

In my project it is necessary to have some specific settings for "normal users" and the normal view for Admin users. But everytime a setting is done I will have to restart the database in order for them to be applied.

An example would be:

```
CurrentDb.Properties("ShowDocumentTabs").Value = False
```

This turns off the document tabs - but only if I restart the database. Is there a way to do this without a reload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, AFAIK.

Startup options are evaluated and applied when opening a database.

Comment: Thank you. I have done some more research on this and found exactly this answer several times. I have now added this to my startup functions of my database which works perfect.